# How to make the center of a text of a child view is the center of its parent view?

Tags: android, xml, layout

As shown in the pic below, I want the text of each `button` to be centered, not in the sense of that, the text should be started to be written from the center but in the sense of, the center of the text should be also the center of the view.

i used in the xml file, the `gravity` property and `layout_centerInParent="true"` as well, but as you see below, the text started to be written from the center of the view.

please let me know which property can do this job?

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/et_IP"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="IP Address" />
 <EditText 
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_IP"
    android:id="@+id/et_port"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="1883" />
   <Button 
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_port"
    android:id="@+id/bt_connect"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Connect..."/>
  <Button 
    android:layout_below="@+id/bt_connect"
    android:id="@+id/bt_clear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Clear"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/bt_clear"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_response"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="NO_RESPONSE"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

***Pic***
[image]

Comment: I think you need a customview to do this

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like this to center the button on the page and also in the view. Here is a small example that could be helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
<LinearLayout>
<!-- Add other controls that you dont want with buttons --></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_form" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_button"
            style="@style/Button.Green"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/OK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/unlock_button"
            style="@style/Button.Green"
            android:layout_width="136dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/unlock" />

           <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset_password_button"
            style="@style/Button.Green"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:text="@string/force_reset_password" />
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Merge is a great tool to implement views/layouts if you are working in hierarchies. Hope it helps :)

Comment: hi, i tried <merge> without specifying any margins and it did not work? what is the use of merge the?

Comment: The <merge /> tag helps eliminate redundant view groups in your view hierarchy when including one layout within another. For example, if your main layout is a vertical LinearLayout in which two consecutive views can be re-used in multiple layouts, then the re-usable layout in which you place the two views requires its own root view. However, using another LinearLayout as the root for the re-usable layout would result in a vertical LinearLayout inside a vertical LinearLayout. The nested LinearLayout serves no real purpose other than to slow down your UI performance.